# Create a fake depth encoder signal on a surface system?

Tags: signal, encoder

I am trying to create a test box which will do away with the actual depth encoder as it is awkward to have out all the time the encoder is similar to this: http://www.encoderonline.com/UK/Data-Sheets/Incremental/Data-MXE.htm

The unit it is connected to outputs 9V DC on between the encoder + and - for both the A and B signals.

I would like the circuit if possible to be able to change direction

Comment: How will you command the motion? Does it have to "turn" very quickly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The encoder has three signals (A,B and O). These are also available as the  inverted signals making six in all.

I would suggest this was an ideal project for an arduino or similar microcontroller.

[image]

Only three signals need to be created (A,B,O) by the controller. A cmos inverter IC (4049) takes care of the inversion.

Answer (score 0):

Jim's suggestion of a microcontroller to simulate the signals seems like the ideal solution. However if you're only using the A and B signals and you're after something simpler but that will require manual rotation there are quite a few small and cheap rotary encoders that could be used. The following [rotary encoder](https://www.sparkfun.com/products/9117) fom Sparkfun is an example of one:

[image: Rotary encoder]